# Setting up proxy headers in IIS for flask application

Tags: flask, iis, reverse-proxy

I have a flask application on windows running at `http://localhost:3333`. I want domain example.com to proxy to this application using IIS. I have setup IIS with below settings.

- Added server variables HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST
- Configured URL Rewrite module to redirect example.com to `localhost:3333`

There is a route in flask which I use to generate URL for forgot password like this `url_for('/password_reset',_external=True)`.

When I access the page via `example.com`, all works fine where I have `redirect()` used. But wherever I have `url_for()`, the URL looks like `http://localhost:3333/password_reset` instead of `http://example.com/password_reset`. How do I make `url_for()` to use the external domain name properly.

Edit 1:
Current web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="http://localhost:3333" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3333/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:3333/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://example.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Host" value="{HOST}" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Edit 2:
Solution: I executed this to preserver headers and now the original host is preserved when using `url_for()`.

```
"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config -section:system.webServer/proxy /preserveHostHeader:"True" /commit:apphost
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module Use outbound rules to modify such URLs in HTTP responses.

Comment: Have added my current outbound rule, still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked, as per edit.
I executed this to preserver headers and now the original host is preserved when using url_for().

```
"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config -section:system.webServer/proxy /preserv
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use iis reverse proxy module for that you need to install arr:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

below is sample rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
       
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
               
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
               
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule2" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="false">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://127.0.0.1:5000/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://example.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
       
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think I already have that, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @0tKali If your issue is solved then post the solution as answer and mark as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.